# Display Design Support Library in palette

Tags: android, palette

Is there any way to add widgets provided by Design Support Library in android studio design palette to drag & drop them in screen?

I am referring to `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`, `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText` etc... in here:

[image]

I use some of them in my app and it compiles/runs on kitkat fine but I have to copy/paste them after googling or from old projects each time.

Am I doing something wrong on including them in my project or there is no way to display them there?